# Screen Reader not finding popUp

Tags: html, css, dynamic, jaws-screen-reader

Currently trying to make a section of a site more readable to screen readers (Jaws, MacVoice over, ect). One of the buttons on the page generates a popup that in turn the user will need to be notified of, the problem is this popup is generated at the bottom of the DOM meaning that the user would have to navigate to the bottom of the dom (tabbing through) in order to even know the page is there. Does anyone know a possible way around this?

Comment: Try reading docs first `role="alertdialog"` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_alertdialog_role)

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing it from the generated place with javascript and append it to a more convienant/logic place for the user. The code should be something like:

```
$('#amoreconvenientplaceforthebuttonID').append($('#mybuttonID'));
$('#mybuttonID').remove();
```

Comment: Seems like a solid way of going about it. Can you think of anything a little less invasive to the page structure though? I fear that such an operation would have unforsen consequences

Comment: I agree, but as far as i can think right now is the only solution.. OR.. what kind of popup is that? Can you give more details about your code? Mabye you can set the rendering of the popup where you need it.

Comment: In our case. We have a set of different html partials that get appended to the body. Thus at the bottom of the page.

Comment: IS there maybe a screen reader specific " Focus" that could focus on the new element? Maybe something from the ARIA functionality built into html?